# How to ignore type check for unused parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

TypeScript keeps complaining about `Parameter _args implicitly has an 'any' type`. I have to add `any` types for unused parameters. Tried skipping with `_` underscore in front but does not work.

```
...

    post: (_parent: any, _args: any, {user}: {user: any}) => {
      if (!user) throw new Error('No user')
      return true
    },

...
```

How do I ignore type check for unused `_args` and destructured parameters `{user}: {user: any}`?

I just copied `tsconfig.json` from MS's node-typescript-starter repo.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*", "types/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

---

Stack: TypeScript (v3.9.7), Node (v12.18.3), Apollo-server-koa (v2.16.1)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I ignore type check for unused and destructured parameters, {user}: {user: any}

Destructure it into a variable with the name prefixed with `_`

## Before

```
{user}: {user: any}
```

## After

```
{user: _user}: {user: any}
```